# Pass a direct value to CreateIoCompletionPort()'s CompletionKey parameter

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock, iocp

When using `CreateIoCompletionPort()` to associate a `SOCKET` with a completion port, can I pass a direct value (i.e. not a pointer) to the `CompletionKey` parameter, or should I only pass a pointer?

What I want to do is to pass the `SOCKET` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CompletionKey` parameter to [CreateIoCompletionPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862.aspx) is of type `ULONG_PTR`. It is large enough to hold a `ULONG` or a pointer type, whichever is larger. You can pass any value, that fits in a `ULONG_PTR`. A `SOCKET` meets this requirement.

See *winsock2.h:*

```
typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET;
```

Comment: So the concept of passing a direct value to a parameter that expects a pointer is not wrong in any way?

Comment: @joseph_m: The `CompletionKey` parameter is not a pointer. It's just **pointer-sized**, allowing to pass a pointer, if desired. As long as you adhere to alignment and size restrictions, you can pass any value through `CompletionKey`, including a pointer.